# How can I set the div to the height of two other divs with javascript while using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using javascript to make images appear in a bootstrap template.  They all have a with of `292.5px` when on a full screen but I would like to make one of the columns set height to the height of two other columns put together.  When looking for help I found this:

```
var right=document.getElementById('box').style.height;
var left=document.getElementById('slideshow3').style.height;
if(left>right)
{
    document.getElementById('box').style.height=left;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('slideshow3').style.height=right;
}
```

But it wouldnt work for some reason. And I only need to change `#box` `height` to the `height` of `#slideshow4` + `#slideshow5`

Thanks

**---------------Update---------------**

please see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7kpmk56/1/) Thanks

Comment: Please share a JSFIDDLE

Comment: .style is a readonly property and should not be edited. Can you try using setAttribute and see if it works? `document.getElementById('element').setAttribute('style', 'height:value')` ?

Comment: @SatejS please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7kpmk56/1/) Thanks

Comment: @JermyRajan please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7kpmk56/1/) Thanks

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? Couldn't `flex` do it?

Comment: @Akxe no flex doesn't exactly work here later this moves on to mobile so it gets a bit complicated.

Comment: @Sammy7 Well mobile do handle flex well and you could use media query to do the trick for smaller screens... This case is perfect for flex, but maybe I haven't  understood the problem right

Comment: @Akxe could you please see the jsfiddle and try it on there.  I actually just tried putting it on and it seems to change the size of everything not just what I need.

Comment: What about tables? https://jsfiddle.net/v7kpmk56/2/

Comment: Even better read trough the JS and made few optimizations https://jsfiddle.net/v7kpmk56/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right except that style.height properties are not straight numbers ie.. 10px or 100% so you cant compare the raw values, you must parseInt() them first or use .offsetHeight instead (or both) and then add the unit type back when setting them. Please note: .style properties ARE read/write. Also the .style.height property must be set in code before you can read it (so use offsetHeight instead) You are also missing the id attribute in your box div eg.. `<div class="box" id="box" style="height: 185px;">`

To fix your code above:

```
var rightHeight=parseInt(document.getElementById('box').offsetHeight);
var leftHeight=parseInt(document.getElementById('slideshow3').offsetHeight);
if(leftHeight>rightHeight){
    document.getElementById('box').style.height=leftHeight+'px';
}else{
    document.getElementById('slideshow3').style.height=rightHeight+'px';
}
```

The answer to your question:

```
var height1=parseInt(document.getElementById('slideshow4').offsetHeight);
var height2=parseInt(document.getElementById('slideshow5').offsetHeight);
document.getElementById('box').style.height=(height1+height2)+'px';
```

Comment: Thanks @bug I think you might just be my solution.  it works on my jsfiddle example.  I'll test it on my actual project and be back.

Comment: Just to make sure.  This will work for all browsers running js right?

Comment: Thanks, again.  I had to make some adjustments with my text(removing margin and replacing with padding) but it all worked out perfect.  Thanks so much.  God Bless.    P.S. Bounty reward in 18 hours.

Comment: The code is cross browser and will also work with old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

So, in your jsfiddle, `box` is a class, not an id, so it's `.box` and not `#box`.

If you want to set its height to be the sum of slideshow3 and slideshow4's height, use:

```
$('.box').height($('#slideshow3').height() + $('#slideshow4').height());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function out

```
//sets the height of an element equal to the combined total height of the specificed slideshow id's
function setHeight(elementClass, slideshowIdArray){
    var totalHeight = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < slideshowIdArray.length; i++){
        totalHeight += parseInt($('#slideshow'+slideshowIdArray[i]).height());
    }
    $('.'+elementClass).height(totalHeight);
}
```

I forked your jsfiddle to provide a working example.

[located here](https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/1b60uffw/2/)

I call this function once during intial page load and pass the box class to it along with an array of the two slideshows you want to match height.

I assume you want slideshow 6 to be flush along the bottom in relation to all other slideshows on the page, however, it seems that the H5 tag inside your box div has a margin set on it and this causes slideshow6 to be pushed slightly lower than the other slideshows. This can be adjusted using CSS (removing the margin), or the javascript can be altered to account for this. Your choice

Comment: Your option also works but I like @bug ('s) better. Thank you for your input. Also bug forgot to mention that the margin would mess it up.  But from reading your response I was able to fix that.  Thanks, and God Bless.

Comment: No problem :] I would go with his too since you were already familiar with it. @emackey also has a nice answer that takes care of everything in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery` like this, It may help you

```
left = $("#left").height();
right = $("#right").height();
if(left<right)
  $("#slideshow3").height(right);
else
  $("#box").height(left);
```

Comment: I'm trying to get height of `slideshow3` and `slideshow4` and set it to `box` please see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7kpmk56/1/) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo since you have not provided the HTML . Here is what I did

HTML

Please not the use of inline & block level elements

```
<span id="box">
<div id="cl1" class="c1"> Column 1</div>
<div id="cl2" class="c1"> Column 1</div>
</span>
<span id="slideshow3"> Column 3</span>
```

Javascript

```
var left = document.getElementById('box').offsetHeight
var right = document.getElementById('slideshow3').offsetHeight
if(left>right){
    document.getElementById('slideshow3').setAttribute("style","height:"+left+"px");
   }
   else{
document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("style","height:"+right+"px");
        }
```

CSS

```
    span{
  width:292.5px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.c1{
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#slideshow3{
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4sc3a3d4/)

Comment: HTMLElement.style.height ;) use it instead of HTMLElement.setAttribute()